# Action bar icon Not displaying in some activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

Issue is that i have multiple activities in my application and I am sharing an action bar icon with multiple activities.

Icon is displaying in most of them but missing in one activity.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to this problem is to check the type of your activity.

You need to make sure that you are extending your class with 'ActionBarActivity' instead of 'Activity'.

```
public class MyMainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
```

It is a very small problem. However, Lint will not report it & silently not display the icon in toolbar and you'll wonder what is going wrong here..

Comment: Yeah "very small problem" if you put aside the fact that your activity would crash on a pre-4.0 device. That would be a good hint that something is wrong.